# Approaches to forecasting hundreds of time series at once

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, modeling

I have several hundred time series that I need to forecast for. Some of these time series have a machine id number in common and provide somewhat similar behavior. Some of the time series are also for periodic daily, monthly and yearly values (not necessarily the same series that have the same machine ID).

I have two questions I am thinking over:

1) How to leverage common information for those time series that have the same machine ID (or other another type of clustering)

2) If I am measuring my performance for all the series as a whole by averaging their RMSE, what is the best way to go about validation?

My thoughts so far:

For 1) Develop a meta model for series with similar machine ID's. Use a smoothing parameter in an additive model for the individual time series predictions.

For 2) For ease of coding do k-fold cross-validation of samples from the following:

series1[1:t] --> series1[t:t+h]

series2[1:t] --> series2[t:t+h]

...

seriesN[1:t] --> seriesN[t:t+h]

The other obvious choice would be step-wise cross-validation of each time series and the average the cross-validated scores from all models. This is not only more complex from a computational standpoint, but also this strategy seems to focus more on how each individual prediction performs as opposed to my strategy towards modeling all the series as a whole.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you say more about the nature of the time series (frequency, what is measured, ...) and the question you want to ask of the data? There are many different possibilities for your analysis, and to say much we need to know your WHY

Comment: I don't know too much about the nature of the data (it is for an intracompany competition so presumably I'm given someone else an advantage also.) There are over 1000 separate series to model. Each series is forecasting either on a daily, monthly, quarterly or yearly time-step. Each series also has an id tag with it which the share with other time series (there are around 70 id tags).  As far as what they are forecasting, no specifics are given although the id tags obviously give an indication as the number of types as well as some series have integer values as well as float.

Comment: The scoring for the competition is a sample of the series using a median of the absolute error. Hope this helps and thanks for the engagement. I'm not looking so much to do well in the competition as deepen my understanding for approaching these types of problems.